# Adding static file directory in django 2.2

Tags: django, geospatial, django-staticfiles

I am trying ta add static file directory in django 2.2 in Geonode project. While working on a new app in this project, the static files(js, css) are not being loaded. If i add STATIC_FILES url and DIR in settings.py, it gives an error.
I tried
project_name/src/app_name/static.... But the trick is not working guys. any suggestion?

```
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(LOCAL_ROOT, "project_name/src/app_name/static"),
```

OR

```
    STATIC_URL = 'static/'

    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
         BASE_DIR / "static",
         'project_name/src/app_name/static',
        ]
```

Comment: Do you have multiple static directories? Is local root defined correctly?

Comment: the local root is defined correctly. I dont have multiple static directories. When 1st url is not working, i am trying with other url.